# metric continuous function on topological space, continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If I have a two metrizable spaces, each function that is known as continuous in the metric space is also continuous now?

For example, a polynomial will be continuous on the standard topology without additional proof?

Comment: Standard topology of what?

Comment: @uniquesolution by standard I mean the topology that includes all open balls on the real line

Comment: @ClsForCookies  -- Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @uniquesolution Assume we have a continuous function f from Metric space A to metric space B. If I create two topological spaces, that have the same open sets as A and B, is f still continuous?

Comment: Sure, because they will have identical topologies.